# %matplotlib inline and others magic does not working in jupyter notebook on windows 10(32 bit)

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have tried all the matplotlib magic but it does not work and shows error.

[image: images shows the matplotlib magic that i have tried and their errors]

I have tried to google about this and tried all magics the solution suggest like `%pylab inline` ,`%matplotlib`,`%matplotlib nbagg`,`%matplotlib notebook`,`%matplotlib osx` and others but none of them worked and most of them show the same error as above.

Comment: You seem to have a problem with your matplotlib install. Make sure matplotlib is working correctly outside of jupyter first; reinstall if needed.

Comment: outside jupyter the matpln jpyiotlib works fine but in jupyter shows error.

Comment: That is quite unlikely. You may use a different environment "outside of jupyter" (possibly without knowing).